# Homology of the Euclidean space with a closed set removed

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose that $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\geq 1$. Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that  for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\geq 0$, we have $\widetilde{H}_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-A)\simeq\widetilde{H}_{k}(\mathbb{R}^{n}-A)$, where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is identified with $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I know how to prove the statement when $A$ is a discrete finite set, but I am confused if $A$ is something like Cantor set, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have an answer using Mayer-Vietoris sequence and some homotopy equivalences.  Notice that $A \times (0, 1) \simeq A$ as well as that $\mathbb{R}^n - A \simeq (\mathbb{R}^n- A) \times (0,1)$.  Also, note that $R^{n+1} - A \times [0,1] \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n+1} -A$.  Let $U = \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty) - A \times [0,1] \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^n \times (-\infty,1) - A \times [0,1] \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Then, we have that $U \cap V = (\mathbb{R}^n-A) \times (0,1)$ and that $U \cup V = R^{n+1} - A \times [0,1] $.  Now, we look at the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.  Notice that $\tilde{H}_k(U) \cong \tilde{H}_k(V) \cong 0$ because they are homotopic to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Therefore, we have that

> $\tilde{H}_{k+1}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - A) \cong \tilde{H}_{k+1}(U \cup V)  \cong \tilde{H}_k(U \cap V)\cong \tilde{H}_k(\mathbb{R}^n - A) $.

Please check the homotopy equivalences to make sure I did not make any errors, but this seems correct to me.